# Querying two SQL-Tables with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, syntax

I got a table `Peoples` and a table `PeopleRequirements`.

`PeopleRequirements.PeopleId` is assigned with a FK Constraint to `Peoples.Id` and also contains a bit (boolean) field `PeopleRequirements.IsActive`.

Now I want to query all people to which a row in `PeopleRequirements` exists (where a row exists that equals `PeopleId == People.Id`) and the `PeopleRequirements.IsActive` field is `true`.

How can I achieve this with EF4 and LINQ?

I've already tried using the NavigationProperties:

`e.QueryableSource = _dataContext.Peoples.Where(a => a.EMail != string.Empty && a.EMail != null && a.PeopleRequirements.Count > 0);`

Comment: Oh, yeah, right - will add this. Sec

Comment: Is People:PeopleRequirements a 1:1 or 1:Many?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normally not how you would do things in EF, normally you would use a Navigation Property in your model to link the two entities. Having said that heres the linq you would use if they are not linked in a normal way.

```
from pplReq in PeopleRequirements
from person in People
where pplReq.PeopleId == person.Id
where pplReq.IsActive
select pplReq;
```

EDIT: Based on your update around navigation properties you can use

```
from pr in _dataContext.PeopleRequirements
where pr.People != null
where pr.IsActive
select pr
```

this will find all PeopleRequirements which are active and are linked to an actual person

EDIT: heres the converse case, people with attached active requirements

```
from person in _dataContext.Peoples
from req in person.PeopleRequirements
where req.IsActive
select distinct person
```

im not too sure if you need the distinct or not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I have edited my post to clarify that there are indeed NavigationProperties present :)

Comment: Hmm I might miss out something, but doesn't your edit fetches the PeopleRequirements instead of the Peoples that have a Requirement attached?

Comment: Yeah it does did you want it the other way around? people with attached active requirements?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to get the people that have attached active requirements